# Drupal Views - Pager on custom feed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I created a custom feed using Drupal 7 views to act as a client and consume results from an external restful api. I can get the content correctly into views and to display on the site. However, I can't seem to get the pager to work. Do I need to add something to my code to get the pager to work? My work is based off of https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/building-views-query-plugins-part-3#comment-16050 along with some other similar tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

By Pager, do you mean a simple << and >> links or a full pager with numbers and links?
Assuming its a simple << and >> links, you can use the "Views Simple Pager" module and you can fetch a new set of values into your array and reiterate. However, I don't see the approach link you've shared has any provision for determination of overall data size/page count to create a numbered pager. In that case, you may need to separate the REST call into two, 1 for Index building and another for actual page views.

Comment: I think that you're correct, but the problem is I don't know where to start on programming this. For example, I can retrieve the total number of results, e.g. 20. But how do I store this to do the index building?